Pixel 8a quick settings tiles edit
I'm trying to modify the quick settings tiles on a Pixel 8a (Android 14) so that I have instant access to the mobile data tile (and preferably wi-fi also) without having to navigate via the "internet" tile.
I did this on a Moto G Pro 2020 with Android 12 via ADB tools:

install android-tools-adb on computer
Settings > About Phone > Build Number 7 times
Settings > System > Developer Options > USB Debugging mode
plug phone into computer
file transfer (MTP) mode
adb devices, confirm on phone, then run again
adb shell
settings put global settings_provider_model false
settings put secure sysui_qs_tiles "wifi,cell,$(settings get secure sysui_qs_tiles)"

But I understand the exact commands vary by phone and Android version and can really mess things up if you get it wrong. So wanted to confirm first that this approach is still valid for Pixel 8a and Android 14? And if not, what are the correct commands?

On Pixel 8, with Shizuku and better internet tiles, it's possible. Should be on 8a too. If it works, please make an answer yourself (permitted here to answer your questions yourself)

adb (USB debugger mode) works independently of other USB modes. Therefore you don't have to activate MTP mode. Where have you found the two last settings commands?

@beeshyams thanks for this - looks perfect except having to start the server after each boot unless I'm root. Gonna put that in the maybe pile.

@Robert I got those commands whenever it was that Android 12 landed on the 2020 Moto G Pro... so a while back. So no idea. They've just been saved in a text file since then.
